# How to save two forms in same template in models

Tags: python, html, css, django, django-templates

This is my template. I have got 2 forms , one is for submitting the test and other is for subtest.When I try to submit one form, I get not null_constraint error .

```
         <form method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="icon-holder">
          <i data-modal-target="test-popup" class="icon-cross"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="input-group">
          <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Test name" />
        </div>
        <div class="button-group">
          <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div id="menu-test-popup">
         <form method="POST">
          {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="icon-holder">
          <i data-modal-target="menu-test-popup" class="icon-cross"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="input-group">
          <label for="test-select">Test Name:</label>
          <select name="test-select" id="test-select">
            {% for test in test %}
        <option value="{{test.name}}" name="choices">{{test.name|title}}</option>
        {% endfor %}
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" name="subtest" placeholder="SubTest name" />
    </div>
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" name="reference" placeholder="Reference rate" />
    </div>
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" name="unit" placeholder="Unit" />
    </div>
    <div class="button-group">
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </form>
```

this is my models . In my models I have test and subtest.

```
  class Test(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Subtest(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    test = models.ForeignKey(Test,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='subtest',blank=True, null=True)
    unit = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    reference_value = models.IntegerField()
    selected = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

this is my view. And the 2nd one is the template_context_processor for my convience

```
def home(request):
    name = None
    if request.method == 'POST':
        name = request.POST.get('name')
        choices = request.POST.get('choices')
        subtest = request.POST.get('subtest')
        reference = request.POST.get('reference')
        unit = request.POST.get('unit')
        test = Test()
        subtest = Subtest()
        test.name = name
        subtest.test = choices
        subtest.name = subtest
        subtest.unit = unit
        subtest.reference_value = reference
        test.save()
        subtest.save()
        print(name)
        return redirect('home')
    return render(request,'main.html',{})   

def list_subtest(request):
    return {'subtest':Subtest.objects.all(),'test':Test.objects.all().prefetch_related('subtest')}
```

Comment: Can you include the stacktrace of the error?

Comment: @markwalker_   return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
sqlite3.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: lab_test.name

Comment: Be aware that approaching it this way completely skips django's forms. So all the built in validation & safety they provided isn't utilised if you create your own markup & handle the `POST` like this.

Comment: @markwalker_ I have got javascript form. If I use the django form it gets all messy.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `subtest.test` to a `Test` instance, probably the one you just created.

```
    #subtest.test = choices  # can't be right
    # might be OK with chosen = Test.objects.get( whatever = choices)

    test.save()
    subtest.test = test  # NB  ... or chosen if above is what you intended
    subtest.save()
    print(name)
    return redirect('home')
```

Note: if you are intending to select a `Test` for `subtest`, Django provides [forms.ModelChoiceField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield) to pick from a queryset.

Comment: what should I include or remove .. I didn't get you?? Can you please explain your answer

Comment: Look at the five lines that aren't comments. Four are from what you posted. The second  is the one you need to fix your error, but I don't know what Test instance you want your new subtest to refer to through its ForeignKey.

Comment: @manish `subtest.test = choices` is where you're going wrong. The FK field needs to be an instance of the related object when you save a `Subtest`

Comment: @markwalker_ cna you please write the answer . I didn't get you . That would help a lot.PS. The error I get is not null constraint failed

Comment: @nigel222 I want to get the test that I select in the template. The test that you have written is for other form . So what should I do ?

Comment: What you get as `choices` is a text string. What you need is a `Test` instance. You have to get the object matching that text string. It's possibly `subtest.test = Test.objects.get(name=choices)`.

Comment: ... but I really think you should learn to use Django forms, instead of rolling your own request.POST processing. You use `prefix` if you want two forms in one view.

Comment: @nigel222 Sorry for being annoying. The choices I get is none. How?? When I click on the test name I have The console prints none.